# If $g \circ f$ is injective and $f$ is surjective, then $g$ is injective.

Tags: functions, proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

> Let $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to C$ be functions.
>
> If $g \circ f$ is injective and $f$ is surjective, then $g$ is
>   injective.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606257/if-g-circ-f-is-inyective-and-f-is-surjective-then-g-is-injective) question that correctly proves this theorem, but my proof seems to be different, so I'd like clarification on whether it's correct.

**My Proof**

We want to show that, for any $b_1, b_2 \in B$, $g(b_1) = g(b_2)$ iff $b_1 = b_2$.

Let $g(f(a_1)) = g(f(a_2))$, where $a_1, a_2 \in A$.

$\therefore f(a_1) = b_1$ and $f(a_2) = b_2$, where $b_1, b_2 \in B$. (Since $f$ is surjective.)

$\therefore g(b_1) = g(b_2)$, where $b_1 = b_2$. (Since $g \circ f$ is injective.)

$\therefore$ $g$ is injective. $\ \ \ Q.E.D.$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please review my proof and elaborate on anything I've done incorrectly.

Comment: The phrasing is a bit awkward, for instance when you say "$g(b_1)=g(b_2)$, where $b_1=b_2$".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh? It looked different to me. So my proof is also correct?

Comment: @57Jimmy Awkward phrasing, but is the proof correct? And how would you suggest I improve the phrasing?

Comment: Why don't you just compare line by line with the proof by Andre at the duplicate?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews consider $f: \{1\}\to\mathbb{Z}$, $f(1)=1$, and $g:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$, $g(k)=1$.

Comment: Yeah, misread the order. @ThomasGrubb

Comment: I do not know if it is correct, because I do not know exactly what you mean: what is a consequence of what? Where are things defined? My improvement would coincide with the proof you have linked. Also, notice that the triple point is not just a bullet point, but a logical symbol that means "therefore" (maybe you used it with this in mind, but again, I am not sure, so I just wanted to point it out)

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong because you are not starting with the hypothesis you are given.  You want to show that $g(x) = g(y) \implies x = y$, so you have to start with the assumption that $g(x) = g(y)$.  So begin with:

> Suppose $g \circ f$ is injective and $f$ is surjective.  We will show
>   that $g$ is injective.  Suppose $b_1, b_2 \in B$ with $g(b_1) = g(b_2).$  Then...

Comment: If I change my hypothesis to be the same as what you've described, would it then be correct? In other words, is the rest of the proof correct?

Comment: Well, nearly, if you move some things around and add some words... :)

Answer (score 1):

There are the following main problems:

- Start by saying "Assume that $g(b_1)=g(b_2)$. We want to prove that then $b_1=b_2$".
- $a_1$ and $a_2$ are not defined in your argument, but you want them to be pre-images of $b_1$ and $b_2$, and they exist because $f$ is surjective. You should say this explicitly and before using them. For instance: "Since $f$ is surjective, there exist $a_1,a_2 \in A$ such that $f(a_1)=b_1, f(a_2)=b_2$."
- Then follows the observation that $g\circ f(a_1) = g(b_1) = g(b_2) = g\circ f (a_2)$. Since $g \circ f$ is injective, this implies that $a_1 = a_2$.
- From the equality $a_1 = a_2$ it follows directly that $b_1=f(a_1)=f(a_2)=b_2$. Hence the claim is proved.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

1) Want to show that $g$ is injective.

Let $b_1,b_2 \in B$, and let $g(b_1)=g(b_2)$.

2) Since $f$ is surjective there are $a_1,a_2 \in A$ with

$f(a_1)=b_1$, and $f(a_2)=b_2$.

3)Consider $g \circ f:$

$g(f(a_1))= g(b_1)$,  $g(f(a_2)) = g(b_2)$.

We have

$g(b_1)=g(b_2)$ 
(see point 1) above),

$g(f(a_1))=g(b_1)= g(b_2) = g(f(a_2)).$

4) Since $g \circ f$ is injective $a_1=a_2$.

5) Then $f(a_1)= f(a_2)$ , hence

$b_1 = f(a_1) = f(a_2) = b_2.$

6) We have shown:

$g(b_1)=g(b_2)$ implies $b_1=b_2$,

$g$ is injective.