# Proof that if the Composition of g and f is one-to-one and f is onto, then g is one to one

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How to prove the following

If $g\circ f$ is one-to-one and $f$ is onto, then $g$ is one-to-one.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606257/if-g-circ-f-is-injective-and-f-is-surjective-then-g-is-injective

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g(x)=g(y)$ for $x,y$ in the domain of $g$.
As $g \circ f$ is defined, the domain of $f$ must equal the domain of $g$, and
$f$ is onto, so there are $x',y'$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x')=x$ and $f(y')=y$.

Now it's easy to see that $(g \circ f)(x') = g(f(x'))=g(x)=g(y)= g(f(y'))=(g \circ f)(y')$ and so by injectivity of $g \circ f$ we conclude $x=y$ and we're done.